# How to solve this menu?

Tags: html, css

I'm having this problem with a page I'm creating.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9lMv.png)

Here is the code for the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>JJ TECH</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="interface">
        <header id="cabecalho">
            <nav id="menu">
                <h1>Menu Principal</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="ativo">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="info.html">Informações</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit ferri facilisi has an, eos probatus perpetua maluisset ad. Minim ponderum pro ut, cu vim referrentur philosophia, ex posse causae signiferumque mei. Dico erant veniam sea et, ut elitr ponderum delicata sed. Tation euismod vix ex, usu latine omnesque no. Vel no libris maiestatis.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

and css:

@charset "UTF-8";

```
            body{
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                background: #370b44;
            }

            div#interface{
                width: 900px;
                background: #fff;
                margin: -20px auto 0 auto;
                padding: 20px;

            }

            p{
                text-align: justify;
                text-indent: 30px;
            }


            /*CONFIGURAÇÃO DO MENU*/

            nav#menu h1{
                display: none;
            }

            nav#menu ul{
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
                overflow: hidden;
                list-style: none;
                display: block;
                font-size: 13pt;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            nav#menu li{
                float: left;
                /*border-right: 1px solid #555;*/
            }

            nav#menu li:hover:not(.active){
                background: #000;
            }

            a{
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 15px;
            }

            .ativo{
                background: #751891;
            }
```

How can I make my content come after my menu, not under it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your css for `div#interface`

```
 div#interface{
            width: 900px;
            background: #fff;
            margin: 67px auto 0 auto;
            padding-top: 20px;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your navigation is position fixed, you have to push down the content using padding or margin. First set body margin to 0. Then add padding-top: 60px; to div#interface. That should be a good starter. And of course try to learn something about block elements, inline elements, floating elements and check their different behavior regarding layouting.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help:
Change it according to your requirements. Especially add style in separate file. 
You need to shuffle your HTML markup and add position fixed to   `div#interface` I suggest change its width to `100%`
here is the working code:

```
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>JJ TECH</title>
        <style>
         body{
                    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                    background: #370b44;
                }

                div#interface{
                    width: 900px;
                    background: #fff;
                    margin: -20px auto 0 auto;
                    padding: 20px;
                    position:fixed;
                    top:71px;

                }

                p{
                    text-align: justify;
                    text-indent: 30px;

                }


                /*CONFIGURAÇÃO DO MENU*/

                nav#menu h1{
                    display: none;
                }

                nav#menu ul{
                    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
                    overflow: hidden;
                    list-style: none;
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 13pt;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    position: fixed;
                    width: 100%;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                }

                nav#menu li{
                    float: left;
                    /*border-right: 1px solid #555;*/
                }

                nav#menu li:hover:not(.active){
                    background: #000;
                }

                a{
                    display: block;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #fff;
                    padding: 15px;
                }

                .ativo{
                    background: #751891;
                }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
     <header id="cabecalho">
                <nav id="menu">
                    <h1>Menu Principal</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html" class="ativo">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="info.html">Informações</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>

        <div id="interface">

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit ferri facilisi has an, eos probatus perpetua maluisset ad. Minim ponderum pro ut, cu vim referrentur philosophia, ex posse causae signiferumque mei. Dico erant veniam sea et, ut elitr ponderum delicata sed. Tation euismod vix ex, usu latine omnesque no. Vel no libris maiestatis.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
```